# Как сделать чтобы скрипт срабатывал для множества элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как изменить данный скрипт чтобы он срабатывал для множества элементов с одинаковыми классами (для блога), он работает только для первого элемента, при наведении курсора на последующие элементы ничего не происходит.

```
let [frontBlock, backBlock] = [
  document.querySelector('.frontBlock'), document.querySelector('.backBlock'), 0
]
frontBlock.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target && e.relatedTarget && e.target.closest('div') !== e.relatedTarget.closest('div') && e) {
    e.target.closest('div').style.display = 'none';
    backBlock.style.display = 'block';
  }
})

backBlock.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  if (e.target && e.relatedTarget && e.target.closest('div') !== e.relatedTarget.closest('div')) {
    e.target.closest('div').style.display = 'none';
    frontBlock.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

Т.е. вот такой код блога, для первого контейнера этот скрипт работает, при наведении мышки на второй и последующие контейнеры ничего не происходит

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock">
    <img src="1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="backBlock">
    <img src="2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock">
    <img src="3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="backBlock">
    <img src="4.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Один блок находится над другим.

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.frontBlock{           
    position: absolute;
}
.backBlock{
    z-index: 9;       
}
```

Comment: Есть два метода: `querySelector()` и `querySelectorAll()`. Подумайте, в чем между ними разница

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я совершенно не разбираюсь в Java, полный ноль, но перед тем как задавать вопрос сюда, я конечно лазил по интернетам  и нашел подобный вариант, заменил querySelector на querySelectorAll после чего скрипт перестал работать вообще, и для первого элемента. Подозреваю что там еще чего-то надо поменять.

Comment: Во-первых, java - абсолютно другой ЯП. Во-вторых, эти два метода возвращают разные типы значений. `querySelector()` возвращает элемент, а `querySelectorAll()` -- коллекцию элементов. Поэтому вам необходимо в цикле перебирать коллекцию элементов, которую вернет `querySelectorAll()`, навешивая события на каждый из элементов

Comment: Спасибо еще раз)) То есть если я даже не понимаю что это не Javа, то я конечно пойму как там чего в цикле перебирать)) Я просто надеюсь что кто-то мне подскажет вроде  "вот это замени на вот это", и всё, хотя из вашего ответа подозреваю что так просто здесь не получится, здесь наверно очень сильно переделывать надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать.. `document.querySelectorAll('.frontBlock')` возвращает коллекцию т.е. `[<div class="frontBlock">frontBlock</div>, <div class="frontBlock">frontBlock</div>]`.

А `document.querySelector('.frontBlock')` вернёт первый попавшийся `<div class="frontBlock">frontBlock</div>`..

```js
const frontBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.frontBlock');

frontBlock.forEach(element => { //цикл по коллекции, берем оди элемент
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => { //Вешаем слушатель
    e.target.closest(".container").querySelector('.frontBlock').style.display = 'none'; //Скрываем элемент на котором висит этот слушатель
  });
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    e.target.closest(".container").querySelector('.frontBlock').style.display = 'block'; //Показываем элемент на котором висит этот слушатель
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.frontBlock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.backBlock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_argentina.jpg"></div>
  <div class="backBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_algir.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_argentina.jpg"></div>
  <div class="backBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_algir.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант без js

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.frontBlock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
.frontBlock:hover {
  display: none; 
}
.backBlock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_argentina.jpg"></div>
  <div class="backBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_algir.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="frontBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_argentina.jpg"></div>
  <div class="backBlock"><img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_algir.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но есть одна проблема, скрипт работает с background, так же он работает если я в style.css вместо background ставлю картинки background-image. Но если я ставлю картинки в сам код HTML, через imd src, он работать перестает, срабатывает один раз, заменяя верхнюю картинку нижней, и все, когда убираешь курсор вообще все исчезает, если посмотреть код в браузере, то у обеих картинок стоит display:none... В общем он работает только с style.css

Comment: @СергейМедведев Проблема в том, что в примере `"Т.е. вот такой код блога.."`, приведенный код не содержит img. `"скрипт работает с background"`, нет. `"В общем он работает только с style.css"` а с чем он должен работать?) Надо почитать что-то и чётко формулировать ТЗ с минимальным самодостаточным примером, а не на ходу дописывать, что там оказывается какой-то img где-то должен быть.. Под своим вопросом жмешь `править` и вносишь все необходимые данные. У тебя должны быть html css js, описание проблемы, чётко сформулированное описание результата, который хочешь видеть.

Comment: Согласен со всеми замечаниями, надо было добавить картинки для примера, но все же мне кажется что блоки <div></div> редко бывают пустыми, беря весь контент только из style.css, тем более если речь идет о блоге... поэтому мне не пришло в голову добавлять туда картинки. Да и вообще я думал что срипту  не важно что в самом блоке содержится, он прописывает свойства самому блоку и все... А оказывается и вот так бывает... Так что это совсем не потому что мне было лень прописать какую-то информацию)

Comment: @СергейМедведев Можно без js ..

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен  вообще  без js, даже не знаю как такой простой вариант сразу мне не попался,  третий день уже бьюсь над этой проблемой)) Надо  было просто в HTML frontBlock и backBlock поменять местами,  и добавить вот такой CSS `.backBlock{
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
}
.backBlock:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: На здоровье! Всё гениальное просто.. :)